# Checkout querySelector

Tags: javascript, magento2

I am relatively new to Javascript. I am trying to get the Price Value on our Checkout page.

document.querySelector returns different values if the checkout is made via Prepayment and Paypal.

Here is my code:

```
function() {
  try {
    var Prepayment = document.querySelector(".order-number>strong").innerText.trim();
    var Paypal = document.querySelector(".checkout-success>p>span").innerText.trim();
  
    if (document.querySelector(".order-number>strong") != null) {
      return capturedText;
    } else {
      return Paypal;
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Upon using the Tag manager, the Tag is giving me "" value.

Can someone help me how do i execute the queries with the QuerySelector within the If / Else environment, so does the function cannot block the entire script if my element which I am looking was not found.

Comment: Please post the template aswell

Comment: Hi Nitheesh,  I am using a custom Javascript to track the Purchase ID. As Peter edited, I ran the test Order, but still the Function is returning "" value.

Comment: function() {
  try {
    var Prepayment = document.querySelector(".order-number>strong").innerText.trim();
    var Paypal = document.querySelector(".checkout-success>p>span").innerText.trim();
  
    if (document.querySelector(".order-number>strong") != null) {
        return Prepayment;
 }
    else {
        return Paypal;
    }
  } catch(e) {
        return "";
  }
}